# SASS nesting issue with textarea element

Tags: sass

So I ran into an issue with nesting. I have tried @at-root but this will bring me to ...well yeah the root. Anybody an idea if this is possible?

//sass

```
.form{
     .control{
         height:40px;

         &textarea{
              height: 200px;//wont work
         }
     }
}

textarea.control{
    height: 200px;// what i am looking for
}
```

Comment: i understand... check my edited answer please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you are asking for is not possible. Essentially you're trying to do this:

```
.form {
    .control {
        height: 40px;

        textarea& {
            height: 200px;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this causes the compilation error: `"&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.` This is for a good reason; `&` represents the absolute path of parent selectors. In this case, `&` is `.form .control`, so you'd get `textarea.form .control`. You can prove this to yourself by writing it like this, which will actually compile:

```
.form {
    .control {
        height: 40px;

        textarea#{&} {
            height: 200px;
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you really don't want to do this...

```
.form {
    .control {
        height: 40px;
    }

    textarea.control {
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

... because maybe you don't want to write `.control` twice, then I think the your best option would be to take advantage of interpolation (`#{...}`) like this:

```
.form{
    $controlClassName: '.control';
    #{$controlClassName} {
        height: 40px;
    }

    textarea#{$controlClassName} {
       height: 200px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`&textarea`
prints `.form .controltextarea`

I think in this way can work

```
.form{
    .control{
        height: 40px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, but this isn't the way that i am looking for ;-)

Comment: in some case you can add & operator after the selector... but can generate some issue.